# How to prevent error in compiling jar plugin

Tags: javascript, java, image, imagej, fiji

I keep getting this error when i try to run a a plugin called MicrobeJ in Fiji (ImageJ)

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.setAxisOffset(Lorg/jfree/ui/RectangleInsets;)V
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.setAxisOffset(ResultChart.java:1188)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.setAxisOffset(ResultChart.java:1179)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.getCharts(ResultChart.java:605)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.getCharts(ResultChart.java:577)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.getPanel(ResultChart.java:1335)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultChart.getPanel(ResultChart.java:1328)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultSubPanel.getComponent(ResultSubPanel.java:211)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultSubPanel$OverlayPanel.updatePanel(ResultSubPanel.java:1273)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultSubPanel$OverlayPanel.setPanel(ResultSubPanel.java:1261)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ResultSubPanel.getOverlayPanel(ResultSubPanel.java:221)
at com.ducret.resultJ.ChartRunner.run(ChartRunner.java:26)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at com.ducret.resultJ.NotifyingThread.run(NotifyingThread.java:76)
```

Can someone please help me

adi

Comment: I have the ResultChart.java files but i dont know where to palce them

Comment: As this is very ImageJ-specific, I suggest you ask on forum.image.sc (and link to here for transparency, of course). The missing class is in org.jfree.chart, so make sure you also have jfreechart.jar in a matching version (containing that class) in your Fiji.app/jars folder.

Answer (score 0):

Download jcommon JAR 1.0.23 with all dependencies [Downlaod](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jfree/jcommon/1.0.23/source-code)

Update the Jar with latest one